# I'm reading excel file using Apache POI. Unable to read Date. In excel,date format 2017-03-15 6:00(cell format=custom) & using poi,reading 42809.25

Tags: apache-poi

#  I'm reading excel file using Apache POI. Unable to read Date. In excel,date format 2017-03-15 6:00(cell format=custom) & using poi,reading 42809.25

```
cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
    int dataType = cell.getCellType();
    if (dataType == 0) {
        String cellData1 = NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        return cellData1;

    } else {
        String cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
        return cellData;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which cell i.e. column position say 2 in each row is going to be a date, you can go for `row.getCell(2).getDateCellValue()` directly.

Check out the method in POI's DateUtil class for dealing with dates in Excelsheets, `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted()`

or you can get date as shown below

```
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
{
try {
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  cellValue = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());

} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dhaval :) I tried using your code and some other lines. Now below code is working for me.

```
cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
                    String cellDate1 = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
                    return cellDate1;
                } else {
                    String cellData2 = NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    return cellData2;
                }
            } else {
                String cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
                return cellData;
            }
```

Comment: DateUtil make less code if you know the cell Index, but you did is gud,

Comment: Yes. I surrounded. I didn't paste here try and catch blocks. Anyways thanks :)

Comment: happy to help you :)